# How to draw a specific graph on Cartesian plane with LaTeX, without the equation?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

Say I am given this graph here that I want to replicate on LaTeX. There is no equation given. What is the fastest way of doing it?

I am at beginner level when it comes to Tikz, but I don't mind learning other method too.

Note: this picture is on a pdf file, which is why I can screenshot and post it here. However there are some graphs in the same situation in a hard copy, and I don't want to neglect those as well.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/. They know. I would just draw it in tickz the `\draw` command draws a line between two points, but it accepts control points in between to bend the line, like a spline.